# Identify elements of function javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, facebook-like

I got the function automatically generated by facebook for a like button plugin code. However, I'm not quite sure about the variables in the function, and I would be really grateful if anyone helps me find out what does each mean.

The `html` the function gathers data from:

```
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/yanntiersen.official"   
data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial"></div>
```

The actual javascript function:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I see that the function is called for `(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')`, but I don't really understand how things work.
Can anyone explain me this, please?

Comment: Bujanca, you asked a question and got a load of answers. What you really want to know is a totally different question from the one you actually asked. My suggestion is to create a new question for the second part though you will probably not get many responses as it is very general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function ( d , s , id) {

}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk));
```

Would mean that the following is true

```
d = document;
s = 'script';
id = 'facebook-jssdk';
```

with this knowledge

```
// Get the first <script> tag in the document
var fjs = document.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]

// Return void from this function if '#facebook-jssdk' exists
if ( document.getElementById('facebook-jssdk') ) return ;

// Create a new script tag
var js = d.createElement(s)

// Assign the id to the script tag
js.id = id;

// Assign a source to load asyncrounously into this tag
js.src = '//connect...';

// Insert the script element into the DOM BEFORE the first script tag
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore( js , fjs )
```

Hope that helps

Comment: so is there any way I can find a correlation between my html and the js function? I want to execute this function in a loop with different parameters. For instead of `https://www.facebook.com/yanntiersen.official` I'd have an array with links

Comment: Why would you do that? This function just asyncronously loads the facebook JDK into the DOM. You would call this once and once only...

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to do, this function loads the javascript needed to perform the actions such as like. You will need to refer to the Javascript SDK documentation at developer.facebook.com to actually use it. The HTML you provided uses that SDK. This function does no more than load that into your page.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Create a function taking arguments `d`, `s` and `id`
(function(d, s, id) {

    //Initialise variable js, initialise variable fjs to the first element with the tag 
    //name s
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

    //If the element with id = id exists already, escape from the function.
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

    //Create a new element of type s ('script') and set it's id to id ('facebookjssdk')
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;

    //Set the script's src attribute to the path specified.
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789";

    //Insert the new element immediately before the first <script> on the page.
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

//Call the function immediately with document for d, 'script' for s and 'facebook-jssdk' 
//for id.
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

If you're not familiar with the pattern `(function () {})();`, it's simply a function that encapsulates it's code and calls itself as it's defined.

Comment: so is there any way I can find a correlation between my html and the js function? I want to execute this function in a loop with different parameters. For instead of `https://www.facebook.com/yanntiersen.official` I'd have an array with links

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, this script can only generate one element (#facebook-jssdk) and it creates a link that does a single thing. What do you mean array with links?

Answer (score 2):

basically it does this:

```
Gets the first "<script>" element in the document
If an object exists with the id of "facebook-jssdk" than
    return (dont process the rest of the code)
EndIf
Create a "<script>" element
Set the new "<script>" element's id to 'facebook-jssdk'
Set the new "<script>" element's src location to "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789"
(this loads a javascript file from facebook's server onto the client)
Insert the new "<script>" tag before the first "<script>" tag in the page
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The script is looking for elements with a tagname of 'script' and then gets a reference to the first script object.

It then looks for an element with id of "facebook-jssdk".  If it finds this id, it stops processing.

It then creates a new script tag, sets the id to 'facebook-jssdk', the source to "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789", and inserts the script before the first script on the page.

Comment: so is there any way I can find a correlation between my html and the js function? I want to execute this function in a loop with different parameters. For instead of `https://www.facebook.com/yanntiersen.official` I'd have an array with links

Comment: All this does is add a javascript file.  There's no point to running it more than once.